# python - Improve script and exception handling

Tags: python, function, argparse

I wrote my first python script which read a ini file using configparser.

First my ini file is define like:

```
;ini
[hypervisor1]
name = hyp1
how = ssh
vms = vm1 vm2 vm3

[hypervisor2]
name = hyp2
how = vpn
vms = vm4 vm5 vm6
```

Second my script:

```
import configparser
import os.path
import argparse

file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"config.ini")

parser = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
parser.read(file_path)

def get_args():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--vm", help="display info")

  args = parser.parse_args()

  vm = args.vm

  return vm

vm = get_args()



def print_hyp(name_s):
    for info in parser.sections():
        for key, value, in parser.items(info):
            for value in value.split():   # split whitespace vms value
                if (value == name_s):
                    global info_s
                    info_s = info
                    print(name_s, "is deployed on", info)


if (print_hyp):
        print_hyp(vm)

        name = parser.get(info_s, 'name')
        how = parser.get(info_s, 'how')

        print("Name:", name)
        print("How:", how)
```

So I need to get section which belongs to value: function print_hyp. And when I get it, I have to print other key with their value.

I'm sure my script is ugly, how can I improve it ?

And I have not errors management, for exemple the output with a vm that does not exist:

```
./script.py --vm stackoverflow
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "script.py", line 43, in <module>
name = parser.get(info_s, 'name') 
NameError: global name 'info_s' is not defined
```

Same thing without argument.

Could you help me?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would add

```
vm = get_args()
print('vm', vm)   # to verify vm arg is what you want
```

This `if` doesn't make sense:

if (print_hyp):
        print_hyp(vm)
        ...

Do you want something like `if vm is not None:`?

`print_hyp(name_s)` doesn't return anything.  In prints something(s).  It's use of `global info_s` is unwise.  I use global so little that I don't even remember whether it has to also be initialized outside the function.  I think your function should should return it, or a list of its values, rather than use `global`.

You should also be using the `if __name__=='__main__`:`.  If you don't know what that is for, I'd suggest reviewing some basic script layout documentation.